# Java - java.library.path problem on Linux

Tags: java, linux, native, java.library.path

I am able to run a java program with some dependencies from cmd line on my mac, but when I try to run it on a linux SUSE 11 box I have it comes back with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no myNativeLib in java.library.path
```

This is the cmd line I am running:

```
java -Djava.library.path=../lib -cp ../jar/a-jar.jar:. MyMainClass
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use absolute path for `java.library.path`. At least you eliminate possible problems with relative path resolution.

Also, just to confirm, you do have Linux library in the lib, right? Mac one will not work.

Comment: ... you might be after something there. Will report back!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going go out on a limb and assume(at the risk of a bunch of downvotes) that you are trying to use oracle's native database driver.

If it is indeed a database driver that you are using, you can bail on the native version and simply include the .jar thin client on your classpath by using the -cp extension. This may require some code changes such that you are not attempting to invoke the native driver.

If you are hell bent on using a native driver or you need to because the code relies on it. you need to make sure that the java.library.path variable is set to a directory containing the binary driver files(typically denoted with a .so extension).

Also make sure these driver files(since they are native binary) have been compiled for your distribution of linux and not just conveniently copied from the mac install.

If you are not doing any of these things feel free to ignore everything I've said.

Comment: nopes - no oracle or database drivers unfortunately - but thanks!